# Bonus dice for being descriptive

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-2e

I seem to recall that somewhere there is a rule that states the storyteller can award bonus dice for good player descriptions of actions. Where is this rule (I suspect it's in the orignal core book)? (or am I mistaken)

Comment: Sounds like an Exalted/Scion thing.

Comment: @Jadasc have never played those games

Comment: My gut says this is deep in the text and/or examples. At the very least, it's in every statement on ST discretion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've asked for a Rules As Written answer, so I first checked out the **God Machine Chronicle** book to see if the Rules Update addressed the issue. No change from the **World of Darkness** Core Book is indicated, so I went back to the source. The section on assembling dice pools mentions modifiers based on use of good tools or environmental hazards, but no sign of a "good description" bonus. That's the sort of thing you typically find in pulpier games, like Exalted, Scion, Adventure!, or even the Old World of Darkness.